# redirect from domainX to domainY works, but not on Facebook

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

client just moved his website from domainX to domainY and I use a script in .htaccess to redirect all existings links on domainX/link to domainY/link.

It works, but not with the links that are posted on Facebook because Facebook adds tracking to the URL, so that URL doesn't exist on domainY.

This is what I use now in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainX.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainY.com/$1 [P]
```

How can I make it work that `domainX.com/link&trackingfacebook` goes to `domainY.com/link` ?

Comment: What error  do you get for the links on facebook ?

Comment: No error, it just goes to domainY.com (mainpage).